# Is foldR Tail Recursive in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc, tail-recursion, fold

I'm new to Haskell and reading Haskell from first principles,
in chapter *Folds* page 384 I have came across *FoldR* and seems like its not tail recursive

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

1- can we make it tail recursive ?

2- and do it will be optimized ?

Comment: Not sure why folks are downvoting, as it's a perfectly reasonable question. But, as the answers have correctly pointed out, "tail recursion" isn't really that relevant in Haskell. You're more worried about storage space for thunks (which is the big reason `foldl` is objectively worse than `foldl'`, for instance, despite it being possible to implement both tail recursively in a straightforward way.

Comment: Don't know either why this was downvoted - and I don't think it's really a duplicate of the performance question given. IMHO this question and the answers are good and stand on their own so I'd like to vote to reopen this. Sadly that would instant-reopen it and I don't want to turn this into close/reopen war so what do others think?

Comment: @Carsten  the answers do seem rather different here.

Answer (score 8):

In a lazy language like Haskell, tail recursion is often a bad idea. This is one of these cases.

We might attempt to make `foldr` tail recursive by e.g. starting with a `reverse` (which is also doable in a tail-recursive way), and then accumulating the `foldr` result step by step, in a tail recursive way. However, that would break the `foldr` semantics.

With the standard `foldr`, we have e.g.

```
foldr (\_ _ -> k1) k2 (x:xs) = k1
```

no matter what `xs` is, including a bottom value like `undefined` or an infinite list like `[0..]`. Further, when `xs` is a finite but long list, the code above is also efficient, since it stops the computation immediately without scanning the whole list.

As a more practical example,

```
and :: [Bool] -> Bool
and = foldr (&&) True
```

makes `and xs` return `False` as soon as some element of `xs` evaluates to `False`, without scanning the rest of the list.

Concluding, turning `foldr` into a tail recursive function would:

- change the semantics when dealing with partially-defined lists (`1:2:undefined`) or infinite ones (`[0..]`);
- be less efficient on finite length lists, which would always have to be completely scanned, even when there is no need to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56958943/3862698
here they have defined foldr using continuation (to me it like returning a function) is its optimized to use it in haskell ?
or it will break the semantics  as well ?

Comment: seems like it will break

Comment: but still it would be optimized ? if we don't include bottom and we have strict function passing inside FoldR ?

Comment: @hanan what do you think "optimized" means?

Comment: @hanan You are comparing apples and oranges. My answer considers a __lazy__ language like Haskell, while the answer you mention is about F# which is _eager_, so the semantics is different. Because of this difference, we can't apply the same reasoning to both languages: good practices in one language can easily be bad practices in the other one, and vice versa.

Comment: ^^^ specifically, this "CPS" technique both in F# and Haskell first build an depth-n closure from the n-long list, then applies it to the initial value (called `acc` in the answer you linked). then, in a _strict_ language, a chain of n applications is performed building the result from bottom to the top, which is OK. but in a lazy language the application `cont {func x r}` won't reduce (i.e. evaluate) the application `func x r` -- instead it will be passed as is to `cont`. the effect is two more extraneous traversals, one of which is on stack, with a potential for stack overflow. ... @hanan

Comment: ...  the remedy is to use `(\ r -> cont $! func x r)` as the continuation at each step, to get the needed strictness back. @hanan

Answer (score 5):

`foldr` is not tail recursive ... but it can be used to write functions that process lists in constant space. chi already pointed out that it can implement `and` efficiently. Here's how it can implement an efficient function for summing a list:

```
mySum :: Num a => [a] -> a
mySum xs = foldr go id xs 0
  where
    go x r acc = r $! x + acc
```

How's this work? Consider `mySum [1,2,3]`. This expands to

```
foldr go id [1,2,3] 0
==> -- definition of foldr
go 1 (foldr go id [2,3]) 0
==> -- definition of go
foldr go id [2,3] $! 1 + 0
==> -- strict application
foldr go id [2,3] 1
```

We've reduced the list size by one, and haven't accumulated anything on the "stack". The same process repeats till we get

```
foldr go id [] 6
==> definition of foldr
id 6
==> definition of id
6
```

---

Note: if this code is compiled by GHC with optimizations enabled (`-O` or `-O2`), then it will actually transform it into blazing-fast tail-recursive code without any further assistance from you. But even unoptimized, it will work okay and not burn up a bunch of memory/stack.

Comment: great answer and example

Answer (score 2):

`foldr` is not tail recursive.
Sometime it is called the true "recursive" fold while fold left is "iterative" (because of tail recursion it is equivalent to iteration).

Please note that in Haskell, because of laziness, also `foldl` do not guarantee constant space, that is why it exists `foldl'`

Comment: Can you please Give me the reference of fold ?

Answer (score 2):

`foldr` is not tail recursive itself, but depending on `f`, it is possible that `foldr f` is tail recursive. Tail recursion in Haskell is quite subtle because of lazy evaluation.

For example, consider `f = (&&)`. In this case, we have

```hs
foldr (&&) acc lst =
   case lst of
      [] -> acc
      (x:xs) -> x && foldr (&&) acc xs
= 
   case lst of
      [] -> acc
      (x:xs) -> if x
                then foldr (&&) acc xs
                else False
=
   case lst of
      [] -> acc
      (x:xs) -> case x of
         True -> foldr (&&) acc xs
         False -> False
```

Note that in this case, we clearly see that `foldr (&&)` is tail-recursive. In fact, `foldr (||)` is also tail recursive. Note that the fact that `foldr (&&)` is tail recursive is fundamentally because of laziness. If it weren't for laziness, we would have to evaluate `foldr (&&) acc xs` *before* substituting the result into `x && foldr (&&) acc xs`. But because of laziness, we evaluate `x` first and only then determine whether we need to call `foldr (&&) acc xs`, and whenever we make that call, it's a tail call.

However, in most cases, `foldr f` will not be a tail recursive function. In particular, `foldr ((+) :: Int -> Int -> Int)` is not tail recursive.

Comment: I believe in almost all actual applications, `foldr c n` actually *will* be tail recursive, or at least (approximately) tail recursive modulo cons. There are exceptions, like `data SList a = SCons !a !(SList a) | SNil; fromList = foldr SCons SNil`, where it's reasonable for it not to be, but that sort of thing doesn't show up very often.